# Disable FSCK on all disks but the OS disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fsck

I have a VM that has 4 disks attached to it, and while it runs there is a program written on C# that attached more random disks to it.
I don't know if the randomly attached disks will have interval and count for FSCK, but I don't want to run FSCK on them nor change their data in anyway.
is there anyway to run the FSCK only on OS disk without running it on the attached (not mounted **nor mentioned on the fstab file**)?
When the OS will done starting up i'll run it manually on the disks that i do want to FS Check

Answer (score 2):

To permanently disable `fsck` check on a hard disk partition, you need to edit
[/etc/fstab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html).

The last value when set to `0` will tell fsck to skip checking the partition.

From the man page:

```
The sixth field (fs_passno).
          This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which
          filesystem checks are done at boot time.  The root filesystem
          should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other filesystems
          should have a fs_passno of 2.  Filesystems within a drive will
          be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different drives
          will be checked at the same time to utilize parallelism
          available in the hardware.  Defaults to zero (don't fsck) if
          not present.
```

Comment: i have edited my question thanks to your comment, please have a second look

Comment: As far as I know, fsck cannot be used on a mounted partition as this may damage the filesystem. You might be looking for the `-M` switch to not check mounted filesystems and return an exit code of 0 for them.